# How do I send back a response from my EventHandler to my controller in a microservice architecture with Rabbitmq?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, microservices

Im trying to get going with microservices so Im working on a play project to test it out. My problem right now is registering the user. I have a controller in my Api gateway that takes the request and publishes the event to the service bus (Rabbitmq).

Api gateway Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterUser([FromBody] CreateUser createUser)
        {
            await busClient.PublishAsync(createUser);
            return Accepted($"RegisterUser/{createUser.Email}");
        }
```

After this I just process the command in my Identity application CommandHandler:

```
public async Task HandleAsync(CreateUser command)
        {
            try
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"Creating user: {command.Name}.");

                var user = mapper.Map<UserRegister>(command);
                var userRegistered = await userService.RegisterAsync(user);

                if (userRegistered == null) await busClient.PublishAsync(new CreateUserRejected(command.Email,
                                                                         "The email is already in use", "400"));
                else
                    await busClient.PublishAsync(new UserCreated(userRegistered.Email, userRegistered.Name));

            }
            catch (CustomException ex)
            {
                await busClient.PublishAsync(new CreateUserRejected(command.Email, "Problem saving user.", ex.Code));
                logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

If the user does not exist everything works perfectly. My problem is when the user already exists, I want to send an event back to my Api gateway in the form of `new CreateUserRejected(command.Email,"The email is already in use", "400")`. Now, what should I do? If I create an EventHandler to manage the event how can I send back the message from the EventHandler to the controller (so It can be displayed to my end user)?. My first idea was just to check the local storage in my Api gateway before publishing the request to the service bus, but then why even use events in case of a rejection?. Just looking for the best way to do it.

Comment: You would need to wait for a result you send back through the service bus for confirmation either-way. Having a controller waiting for microservices over a message bus like this for what would be a simple task, seems like hitting an otherwise  simple problem with a sledgehammer. It may be solving a problem, by making yourself 3 more problems

Comment: @TheGeneral I agree it seems like an over kill for such a simple task, thats what i´m asking what would be best to do? The only thing that comes to my mind right now is checking my local api gateway database. Could also be moving my register logic to my identity microservice instead of doing it in my api gateway?

Comment: Why are you calling this a microservice?

Comment: Its hard to get a feel for your architecture here (and terminology), but it seems your controller aught to be blocked and listening for the messages pushed by the create user command as to whether its failed or not.

Comment: @CodingYoshi well its an api that works only as an identity provider, and I have different apis that are decoupled and do different jobs.

Comment: @TheGeneral Well blocking my controller defeats the purpose of using a service bus so I dont really like that idea. My architecture is pretty similar to the one presented in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/data-driven-crud-microservice where I have an api gateway (where my register method is) and I send the command to my Identity api to create the user.

Comment: Then you will need a back channel back to the client to inform them. There are a few options, one is signalr

Comment: This is not a microservice and neither is the example in the MSDN article. They are both simple MVC apps. Yours has a message bus but that doesn't make it a microservice. To answer your question, return a response to the client (202) to tell the client the request is accepted along with a URL to check the state of the transaction. The client will (poll) check the state using the url and get a result stating a success or "The email is already in use." This is not the only solution but one of them.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Is not an MVC app, they are small apis that together form a large system, thats a microservice for me, what is your definition?. Yeah I thought about that but with network latency it can get complicated for a simple task like registering an user.